# Securely send API Requests

Tags: php, api, curl, hash

I need to send the following API request:

```
<?php

$url="http://api.example.com/check_balance.php?username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);


$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    
$json = json_decode($output, true);

?>
```

You can see above that I need to initiate the API URL which contains sensitive information like my username and password. The API provider doesn't accept hashed password.

So my query is that, Is it safe to include my username and password openly on the api url?

Is there any way to protect my username and password from possible vulnerabilities?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for security.stackexchange.com. In short I don't think the username password is the big issue as long as it's just used for that service. It is by no means safe though. Using http instead of https is a major security concern as is sending the login details as URL parameters as this would mean they are displayed in the access.log

Comment: Is it safe to store the username and password (without hashing) to the mysql database? Is there any way to steal the data from database? @dbrumann

Comment: its just as safe as sending it in the request body. is your connection secure? over the open internet, no, that's not secure, people on your wifi, and your ISP, and your firewall operator and god knows who else, can spy on you.  if its on a closed LAN, yeah its probably safe.  if you need safety on the open net though, enforce httpS

Comment: Can I use free ssl like Let'sEncrypt for this purpose to protect my Sensitive information from being stolen? @hanshenrik

Comment: @AmlanDutta storing plaintext credentials in the database is not considered safe. I would not advise doing that, but the assessment for your use case is up to you. If it's "only" your credentials and you can easily renew/invalidate them you might consider it "safe enough". If it's someone else's (read your user's) data, you should definitely not do it.

Comment: @AmlanDutta Do you control the API? If not free SSL will not help you.

Comment: @dbrumann Yes I control the API...

Comment: then yeah, LetsEncrypt that API, and keep port 80 closed (that will make insecure http connections impossible, even by accident)